# como activo un entorno virtual en VScode Python en una terminal Git Bash

Tags: python, vscode, git-bash

El código que he ingresado es este:

```
python -m venv FastAPI
```

Claramente estando ubicado en la carpeta backend que he creado.

Y una vez que he creado el entorno virtual me ubico en ella:

```
cd FastAPI
```

Pero una vez ubicado empieza el problema porque no me deja activarlo:

```
. Scripts/activate
```

Comment: No tienes que entrar en la carpeta en la que creas el entorno virtual para activarlo, ese es tu problema.

Comment: 1. Hay un espacio entre el punto y `Scripts`. 2. "No me deja" es una pésima descripción. ¿hay un mensaje de error? ¿cuál es? o, ¿cómo exactamente "no te deja"?